# What is the main difference between Korg Korg Pa4X and Korg Pa4X Musikant?

Tags: keyboard

I want to buy a new keyboard but I want to know the difference between the normal Korg Pa4X and the Pa4X Musikant (or the Pa3X series). The music I play is mostly East European music, but I also play a lot of Pop. The only thing I found on the net is that the Musikant has about 300 more sounds but how about the styles? They both have 500 styles but are they the same?

Answer (score 1):

no, they are not the same. You can find the style list and also the sound list from both in the manuals you can find on korg website. There you find also a comparing list from pa 3x and 4x. greetings, niccki